# 6 month old Chilli plants are struggling after a strong yield

Tags: chili, outdoor

My chilli plants seem to be having a tough time recently and I can't work out what the problem is. 1 Scotch Bonnet plant seems to be dropping a lot of leaves and yellowing, the other two are mostly ok (1 in particular doing very well) - these are the ones in the planter. I would give them more space, but I don't really have any available. The chocolate hananero (terracotta) hasn't seemed to produced any new leaves in a while (still flowering tho)

All 4 plants have produced a LOT of fruit in the last 2 months. But now that is slowing, I would prefer them to stop growing fruit entirely and get a bit healthier.

I have tried spraying magnesium on the yellowing leaves recently (diluted epsom salts), I use a natural insecticide spray for fruit and veg, and I also use Fish based Charlie Carp fertiliser, and I mist them with water. I think probably a bit too much fertiliser actually, and maybe a bit too much water. I'm trying to avoid watering for a few days (however the chilli habanero starts to wilt within a day)

Any thoughts on rescuing these plants? My thoughts are to top them and trigger some growth on the branches? I've cut new fruit and flowers off the one that's really struggling...is this likely to trigger some growth? I'm in Sydney, facing east so they get a good 6-7 hours of morning sun and the temp is currently hovering around 30C. We still have a good few months of bright sunshine left, and I think I'll try and overwinter these and keep them if possible.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Several of the leaves are perforated. Do you notice visible insects or larva feeding on the leaves?

Comment: Very occasionally I see a couple of white aphids, and then I spray with Eco Bug Organic Vegies Fruit And Herbs, and that seems to stop them in their tracks. I also spray it on semi regularly without seeing any bugs. So I'm pretty sure I catch most of them